# Is there a method of installing debuginfo package without registering RHEL7?

Tags: rhel, software-installation

My `RHEL7` isn't registered just for test. Now I want to install `python-debuginfo rpm` package. But according to [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9907), it seems that I can't install `python-debuginfo rpm` without registration. Is there a method of installing `debuginfo` package without registering `RHEL7`?

Comment: The [centos repos](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/DebugInfo) usually have `debuginfo` packages.

Comment: @Bratchley: According to [this document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Developer_Guide/intro.debuginfo.html): "For example, using a CentOS debuginfo RPM for a Red Hat Enterprise Linux RPM package will not work.".

Comment: Fair enough, that was just an educated guess on my part. You may try downloading the RPM's from the website and transfer them to the test machine. Never done that before either so I don't know if they usually have a lot of dependencies but it might be another way to try to get it to work.